# Remove a cell number from the Twilio unsubscribe list

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a very simple alert mechanism to alert drivers "in-the-field" when a new pickup has been assigned to them. I have had an instance twice where a driver has responded with a STOP and became un-subscribed. Once discovered we acquired the proper opt-in documentation from them. Is there any way to re-subscribe a user that opted out and changed their mind on receiving the messaging. i.e. they issued the STOP to the incorrect SMS. And have deleted the original message to START. Or do I need to code something for them to opt back in

My SendGrid provides a method to remove suppression from email but am not finding anything like that here in Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

They need to send a `START` to the number they previously opted out of, this is currently a requirement. You will also get an error when trying to send messages to them, to alert you they opted out.

[Error 21610 - Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21610)